# <<use>> and <<composition >> at the same time required?

Tags: uml

I have the following **UML** containing the class **School** which (*in my example right now*) can only have one **TeacherRoom**.

My Question now is what is the official notation for this **UML** or should i remove the **<<use>>** assosiation because it is obvious? 
Obvious because i am saving a instance of **TeacherRoom** in my **School** instance?

I would define it like that:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you have attribute `teacherRoom : TeacherRoom` in class `School` implies that `School` is using `TeacherRoom`, so the ≪use≫-dependency is not needed.

You also have a composition association to TeacherRoom. This means that, in addition to the attribute, you have a second relationship with TeacherRoom. So you may remove either one.

Comment: So basically i could have School and TeacherRoom without any association? Btw is "association" the right word here xD

Comment: Yes and yes. But I have worked in teams where they insisted on having both attributes and associations redundantly.

Comment: yeah so you can do it but you dont have to do it because its redundant :) I was thinking exactly like that but its nice to talk about that just in case ;)

Comment: Well, I said 'redundant', but when you have the attribute _and_ the association, then formally it means that there are _two_ separate relationships, i.e. School has two TeacherRooms or School has two references to the same TeacherRoom. If you would like to show both, you could indicate that one is _derived_ from the other, by using a slash: ``/teacherRoom : TeacherRoom``. See https://www.uml-diagrams.org/derived-property.html

Answer (score 2):

According to my understanding of section 10.4 of UML 2.5.1 specification, Usage dependency decribes the fact that a given Component requires an Interface or Services.

So I would remove it, as this has nothing to do with the fact that a "School" is composed of "TeacherRoom".

My second point is your "teacherRoom" property which has more or less the same meaning than your composition so I would remove one of them (Property or Composition).

Comment: I dont think so i think 10.4 cant be the only possibility because if i am using the TeacherRoom or an instance of it somewhere in the code implementation of School i basically <<use>>  it what means i need in that case an <<use>> association. : )

Comment: According to section 7.7.4, the use-dependency just indicates 'usage'. See Figure 7.20. I think 'usage'  is not restricted to components/interfaces/services.

Comment: Table C.1 defines the keyword `use` as _Usage_. Oh well.

Comment: Besides the fig in 10.4 there seems to be only one other example in fig. 7.20

Answer (score 1):

Since you wrote

> can only have one [typo corrected by me] **TeacherRoom**.

you need to add a multiplicity `1` to the right of the association (and as commented and answered to remove the diamond). Also rather than an attribute in `School` you should use a role name `teacherRoom` at the association and make it an owned property by adding a dot.

[image]

---

Some additional remarks to composition: Composition is (my personal impression) something that causes more confusion than it actually helps building models (just look for questions asking about its semantic and/or look out for wrong usage of it). Even worse is the shared aggregation which caused (and causes) even more confusion. Now after many editions, UML 2.5 defines that hollow thingy as what it is: nothing. Just read the box on p. 110. So back to the filled one, the composite aggregation. Basically it's about lifetime of objects, so whether there's an owner of an object who is responsible of its lifetime. When you make a car composed of its wheels, that's obviously not right since the wheel will live on without being attached to the car. Only the car is no longer a car. But that will be expressed by attaching a multiplicity of 4 to the wheel. Any car with not exactly 4 wheels is no longer a car. No composition at all.

So where can you use composite aggregation then? I have only 2 applications in mind. One is for storage managent. Something that had been important in the early days of computing when dinosaurs like me fought along with hard disks at cupboard size that had 20 Megabytes! Only a few border cases still need indication for memory management. The second case would be security. Indication that something has to be deleted along with its parent. And that's still valid. But then this is the only real application for composite aggregation.

Comment: the black dot should be the rectangle i think right? And the rectangle should be on the School class right, as School can exist without TeacherRoom in theorie but TeacherRoom can not exit without School right?

Comment: No. The dot is the notation for "Owned Property" which makes the named role exactly that. It's simply a different rendering of the same thing, but this way things get clearer than when _hiding_ a property in the class compartment.